# Reading the content of a remote file

Tags: java, jsch, channel-api

Is there a way to read the contents of a file in a remote server using jSch. I dont want to scp to my local machine as I can't get permission for that.

Answer (score 0):

open SSH and send the command:

> "cat filename"